# Problema con las Sesiones PHP

Tags: php

buenas espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, acabo de subir mi sistema a un servidor para probarlo, ya que me va bien en mi local.. entonces subi mis archivos y en cuestion me aparecio este error.

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /storage/ssd3/929/8870929/public_html/publico/index.php:1) in /storage/ssd3/929/8870929/public_html/Core/Controller.php on line 4

entonces estuve leyendo y la sesion debo de tenerla en mi primer index, quite la session de mi controlador principal pero ahora en mi index no me lo mantiene. aqui el codigo de mis documentos.

Controlador.php

```
namespace Core; 
defined("APPPATH") OR die("Access denied");
session_start();
class Controller
{
    public function session()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
            header("location: ./home/");
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header("location: ./publico/home/");
} else {

    header("location: ./publico/inicioControlador");
}
```

inicioControlador.php

```
namespace App\Controllers;
defined("APPPATH") OR die("Access denied");
use \Core\View,
    \Core\Controller;

class inicioControlador extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->session();
        $this->empleadosModelo = $this->buscarModelo('usuario');

        View::render("home/inicio");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> "headers already sent"

Esto ocurre cuanto tienes algún otro tipo de información antes de `session_start()` asegúrate de que sea lo primero que tengas al comenzar el archivo, o sea que no haya otro tipo de cosa antes de llamar a `session_start()` como por ejemplo código `HTML`.